# Make a custom UISearchBar with underlined

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I need to make `UISearchBar` without border. I need to insert picture at the end (right corner), remove borders around and make underlined . `UISearchBar` should look like in the picture. Please, help. I'm new in swift, and I don't know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: I think you can write your own custom UIView. It can include UISearchbar, UIImageView(for right corner) and an UIView underline.

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem maybe you know how create searchBar using textField ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom xib view and add text field view as following like as you have provided picture.

[image: Custom Search Bar]

Now, take outlet of `UITextField` and add following code in your custom view's class files. See the code

```
class CustomSearchBar: UIView {

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Outlets
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @IBOutlet weak var txtSearch        : UITextField!


    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK:- Abstract Method
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class func instantiateView() -> CustomSearchBar {
        let customSearchBar = UINib(nibName: "CustomSearchBar", bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomSearchBar

        let uiView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: 24, height: 24))
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_down_arrow").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        imageView.tintColor = .blue
        uiView.addSubview(imageView)

        // Add right button
        customSearchBar.txtSearch.rightViewMode = .always
        customSearchBar.txtSearch.rightView = uiView

        return customSearchBar
    }
}
```

Now, in your `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method add following code to add custom search bar programatically.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar.instantiateView()
        customSearchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customSearchBar.txtSearch.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(customSearchBar)

        customSearchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customSearchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customSearchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        customSearchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {

    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image: Output]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You can download demo from here: https://filebin.net/yyd2jnys0doo2k53/DemoWebViewProgress.zip?t=zev5kf3p